# How to pivot text fields into one in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

Given the following simple example

```
create table #example (
ProductID int,
ProductName varchar(100),
CustomerID int
)

insert #example values 
    (1,'Product 1',100),
    (2,'Product 2',100),
    (3,'Product 3', 101),
    (3,'Product 3', 102)
```

I want to see a result set that has CustomerID, ProductNamesBought where the products are comma separated. e.g.

```
CustomerID ProductNamesBought
========== ====================
100        Product 1, Product 2
101        Product 3
102        Product 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  e.CustomerID, 
        STUFF((SELECT ','+ProductName FROM #example WHERE e.CustomerID = CustomerID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as ProductNamesBought
FROM #example e
GROUP BY e.CustomerID
```

Output:

```
CustomerID  ProductNamesBought
100         Product 1,Product 2
101         Product 3
102         Product 3
```